# IB Designables Failed to render and update auto layout status : dlopen(Cosmos.framework, 1): no suitable image found

Tags: xcode8, ibdesignable

I had successfully integrated 3rd party Library in Swift 3, Xcode Version 8.3.3,
CocoaPods: `pod 'Cosmos', git: 'https://github.com/marketplacer/Cosmos.git', tag: '8.0.2'.`
However, today it stopped working as expected. I get 3 errors in the issue navigator pane.

- > itemfile:///Users/bogdanbarbulescu/Desktop/Brev/Brev/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:
  >   error: IB Designables: Failed to update auto layout status:
  >   dlopen(Cosmos.framework, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
  >     Cosmos.framework: required code signature missing for
  >   'Cosmos.framework'
- 

> file:///Users/bogdanbarbulescu/Desktop/Brev/Brev/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:
>   error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status
>   for ManageFeedbackTableViewController (dmz-jg-rVK):
>   dlopen(Cosmos.framework, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     Cosmos.framework: required code signature missing for
>   'Cosmos.framework'

- > file:///Users/bogdanbarbulescu/Desktop/Brev/Brev/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:
  >   error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status
  >   for DetailViewController (vPa-2A-MKV): dlopen(Cosmos.framework, 1): no
  >   suitable image found.  Did find:  Cosmos.framework: required code
  >   signature missing for 'Cosmos.framework'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code at the bottom of your pod file and re-install the pods. Should work.

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
    end
end
```

Comment: I tried this with my project which included Firebase pod and it introduced 21 new errors!!!